# How could I fill up the svg path that was already crossed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, raphael

I have an object that has to move along a path (behaviour for which I found a solution), but I also have to "fill", with another color, the path that was crossed.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7TPx5/1/) is an example of what I managed so far.
Also the code looks like this:

```
var searchDl = 1;
var l = 0;

// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var r = Raphael(10, 50, 520, 500);

var p = r.path("M150 10 L75 200 L225 200 L325 100").attr({stroke: "#ddf","stroke-width":5}),
    pt = p.getPointAtLength(l);
    e = r.ellipse(pt.x, pt.y, 7, 7).attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#f00"}),
    totLen = p.getTotalLength(),


start = function () {
    // storing original coordinates
    this.ox = this.attr("cx");
    this.oy = this.attr("cy");
    this.attr({opacity: 1});
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    var tmpPt = {
        x : this.ox + dx, 
        y : this.oy + dy
    };
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    l = gradSearch(l, tmpPt);
    pt = p.getPointAtLength(l);
    this.attr({cx: pt.x, cy: pt.y});
},
up = function () {
    // restoring state
    this.attr({opacity: 1});
},
gradSearch = function (l0, pt) {
    l0 = l0 + totLen;
    var l1 = l0,
        dist0 = dist(p.getPointAtLength(l0 % totLen), pt),
        dist1,
        searchDir;

    if (dist(p.getPointAtLength((l0 - searchDl) % totLen), pt) > 
       dist(p.getPointAtLength((l0 + searchDl) % totLen), pt)) {
        searchDir = searchDl;
    } else {
        searchDir = -searchDl;
    }

    l1 += searchDir;
    dist1 = dist(p.getPointAtLength(l1 % totLen), pt);
    while (dist1 < dist0) {
        dist0 = dist1;
        l1 += searchDir;
        dist1 = dist(p.getPointAtLength(l1 % totLen), pt);
    }
    l1 -= searchDir;

    return (l1 % totLen);
},
dist = function (pt1, pt2) {
    var dx = pt1.x - pt2.x;
    var dy = pt1.y - pt2.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
};
e.drag(move, start, up);
```

How should I start? What should I investigate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you effectively trying to create a 'trail' from the start to the current position ?

If so, you probably want element.getSubpath(start, length); Remove and add each move the path. You can't really fill the existing path half through, as you would need to split it, but then you can't move over it any more. So putting a temp highlight path over the existing one should do it.

The additional code as follows...

```
if( highlightPath ) { highlightPath.remove(); }    
pathString = p.getSubpath(0,l);

highlightPath = r.path( pathString )
                 .attr({ stroke: 'blue',  "stroke-width":5});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7TPx5/4/)